# bootstrap multiselect dropdown+disable uncheck for particular option

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-bootgrid, jquery-bootpag

How I can disable uncheck option from the bootstrap multi-select drop-down, actually on load some option by default is checked and I want those options not to be unchecked. Below I am providing an image for better understanding.
[! [Link for the sample image] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDrDv.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDrDv.jpg)

From the above image those three is by default checked while page load and now I don't want to be unchecked those three (**Cheese, Tomatoes, Mozzarella**)

Below I am providing the link of the above requirement.
[Link to the sample code](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ekd8P)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply add disabled (and selected) attributes to the options which you want to keep selected.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rolename">Role Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="cheese" disabled selected>Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes" disabled selected>Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella" disabled selected>Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's important that you only initialize the multiselect after you have set the attributes